# Higher Order Function invocation strange behavior

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, higher-order-functions, nested-function

I have been playing with the code above and still don't know why is it behaving like this:

```
function myforEach(arr, func){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    func();
  }
}
var arr = [1,2,3];

function func2(){
 return 3+3;
}

myforEach(arr, func2); // undefined
```

I create a myforEach function which takes two arguments an array and a function passed as an argument func, which is called below within the for loop 3 times. Then i declare another function func2 which returns the value of adding 3+3. 
Then i run the `myforEach` with the two arguments and i expect to print in the console 3 times the value 6, however what is being returned is undefined.

When i change the func2 statement to:

```
function func2(){
 console.log(3+3);
}
```

and run again i get console logged 6 three times. `myforEach(arr, func2); // (3)6`

Then i change again the func2 statement to:

```
function func2(){
 console.log("hi");
}

myforEach(arr, func2); // (3)hi
```

If Try `myforEach(arr, alert); // (3)alert` however if i try to put alert within func2 without parenthesis `function func2(){alert;} // undefined` but when adding parenthesis `function func2(){alert();}` then it alerts three times

So the question is why is the `function func2(){return 3+3;}` not returning 6 three times? Since within the for loop the func() is in parentheses means any function added is invoked why is not the func2 being invoked properly?

I made some research on stackoverflow but all i could get was the return for some reason gets lost but no further detailed explanation to the why and root cause.

Is late here and i don't know if i am missing something or just too sleepy. Any explanation would be helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is why is the function func2(){return 3+3;} not returning 6 three times?

It is — you're just not doing anything with that return value. You're passing `func2` into `myforEach` and receiving it as `func`, but then:

```
function myforEach(arr, func){
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    func(); // <=== You're not using the return value for anything
  }
}
```

Just returning the value doesn't cause it to be output automatically anywhere.

Note that this would be the case with the built-in `forEach` as well:

```js
console.log("Nothing gets output after this message");
var arr = [1,2,3];
function func2(){
 return 3+3;
}
arr.forEach(func2);
```

`forEach` is intentionally bland, it does **nothing** with the return value of the function you give it. It doesn't remember it anywhere (that would be `map`), output it, sum it up with others (that would be `reduce`, effectively), etc. Your `myforEach` is similarly bland.

Comment: Yeah, but I was expecting the value to be outputted on the console due to the return 3+3 inside the func2, but it seems i was wrong. I was wondering if adding the return to func() within the loop would output 6 three times since the func() is being called 3 times, however, is just outputting 6 once in the console. Is there any reason why? @T.J. Crowder Thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: @AlonsoAhmetaj: Nothing is automatically output to the console except the result of the outermost expression that you typed into it (`undefined`, in your case, because you're calling a function that doesn't set an explicit return value). Changing it to `return func();` exits your `myforEach` on the first loop iteration, so you only see 6 once.

Comment: So what would be the proper way to output it three times, if you don't mind sharing that? I did use console.log on that and i worked but thought would be another way of returning its value three times. Could be also adding it to a variable. Thanks!

Comment: @AlonsoAhmetaj: It's entirely up to you. If you're writing your own function, just put the `console.log` in the function (`console.log(func());` in `myforEach`). If you're using the built-in, usually it would be a wrapper: `arr.forEach(function() { console.log(func()); });`

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to make sure if could be better method to output it three times. :)

Answer (score 0):

The function is returning `6` as expected. you need a means to contain that returned value. if you assign the invocation `func2()` to any variable, its value will be 6